# Can a tool for cracking macadamia nuts be used for cracking hickory nuts?

Tags: equipment, nuts

Chinese hickory nuts (山核桃), or Carya cathayensis, are related to American pecans. Both are species of hickory, Carya illinoinensis.

[Here](https://item.jd.com/10073252594798.html) is an example of Chinese hickory nuts from Changbai Mountain (长白山).

[image]

What tools can I use to crack Chinese hickory nuts?

Can a tool for cracking macadamia nuts, for example, the following two, be used for cracking Chinese hickory nuts? I have the first tool but not the second.

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I've cracked pecans with my hands, anything should work really

Comment: @Esther Thanks, Does  Chinese hickory nut look more difficult to crack than American pecan? Does it look like having thicker shell?

Comment: From the picture these nuts look like they are much harder to crack than a walnut or hazelnut. The macadamia cracker looks like it could get them open but I don't know whether you will get the nuts out in one piece. A fist sized rock works great for almonds so that might also be worth a try.